# Unable to solve ambiguity while finding general solution to $\sin \theta = \sin 9\theta $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am trying to find the general solution to the equation

$$\sin \theta = \sin 9\theta $$

I worked it out into

$\cos 5\theta *\sin 4\theta = 0 $

Solving for $\sin 4\theta = 0$ .  I got $\theta = \frac{n\pi}{4}$  .

Solving for $\cos 5\theta = 0$ .  I got $\theta = \frac{1}{5} (2n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{2}) $.  Which further simplifies down to $\frac{\pi}{10} (4n \pm 1)$.

However the answer for the second part is $\frac{\pi}{10} (2n + 1)$.

I am unable to understand how they got rid of the $\pm$ sign and have $2n$ instead of $4n$.

Also, why can we not directly write the solution to $\theta$ as $\frac{n\pi + (-1)^{n}\theta}{9}$

Comment: The answer $\frac{\pi}{10}(4n \pm 1)$ is essentially the same as $\frac{\pi}{10}(2n+1)$ because $\{4n+1 \, | \, n \in \Bbb{Z}\} \cup \{4n-1 \, | \, n \in \Bbb{Z}\}=\{2n+1 \, | \, n \in \Bbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: As far as $\theta=\frac{n\pi+(-1)^n\theta}{9}$ is concerned. This is also correct. But to solve for $\theta$, you need to split into odd and even $n$. For example, when $n=2k$ is even, then we will have $\theta=\frac{2k\pi+\theta}{9} \implies \theta=\frac{k\pi}{4}$. Likewise you can do the odd case and get the second answer.

Comment: It should be $-2\cos(5 \theta)\sin(4 \theta)$.